# Find all records with same join column data

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have these tables:

**Project**

| id | name | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Swam | 0.0.1 |
| 2 | Dinali | 0.0.1 |
| 3 | Dinali | 0.0.2 |
| 4 | BigR | 0.0.3 |
| 5 | Kale | 0.0.1 |
| 6 | Kale | 0.0.2 |

**Person**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jake |
| 2 | Skye |
| 3 | Kieth |
| 4 | Jim |
| 5 | Eliz |
| 6 | Haun |

**Person_Project**

| id | person_id | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 | 1 |
| 9 | 6 | 1 |
| 10 | 6 | 2 |
| 11 | 6 | 3 |

I want to find all the persons who are working on same projects exact match. From the above data, result should be persons 1 and 5 because they both working on project 1, persons 2 and 3 because they are working on same projects 1 and 2.
Should not return 4 and 6 as there are no other persons working exact projects they are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
 with projects as
  (
   select person_id, STRING_AGG (project_id::varchar,' , ' order by project_id ) project_ids from Person_Project
   group by Person_id
  )
  ,cte as
   (select project_ids from projects group by project_ids having count(*)>1)
  select person_id from projects where project_ids in (select project_ids from cte)
```

OUtput:

| person_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BPC7Zu6o)

Comment: thank you. Sorry I was not clear, i do not want to which person match to which person. Just list of person ids which have exact match projects to some other persons. OutPut will persion_id/1 2 3 5

Comment: @user09 Please check my modified answer.

Comment: thank you. this is exactly what I was looking for. other solution helps to figure out what matches to what

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

This can be optimized.

##### 2x subquery, 1x window function

```sql
SELECT person_id
FROM  (
   SELECT person_id, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY projects) AS match_ct
   FROM  (
      SELECT person_id, array_agg(project_id) AS projects
      FROM   person_project
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
WHERE  match_ct > 1;
```

##### 1x CTE, 1x `EXISTS`

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT person_id, array_agg(project_id) AS projects
   FROM   person_project
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT person_id
FROM   cte c1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM cte c2
   WHERE  c2.projects = c1.projects
   AND    c2.person_id <> c1.person_id
   );
```

In addition, `array_agg()` should be faster that `string_agg()` (also avoiding the cast).

For *large* numbers of persons and/or projects, it should pay to create a temporary table instead of the CTE, add an index on `(hash_array(projects), person_id)`, and compare the hash values.

For very large sets, use `hash_array_extended(projects, 0)` to practically rule out hash collisions.

Related:

- [Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684)